# Is .NET framework 2.0 optional in Windows XP?

Tags: .net, windows, frameworks, windows-xp, .net-2.0

We are consultants who often works on client site on a Windows PC without admin right, which means we can't install anything.

Questions is: if I write my C# application targeting .NET framework 2.0, which is XP's default installation, will it be guaranteed to run on every PC?

In other words, will it be possible that one organization have decided to install XP on their PCs without the .NET framework? Is .NET 2.0 the core of XP, or is it just an optional feature that can be left out?

Comment: .NET 2.0 is an optional component in Windows XP. You cannot count on its presence.

Comment: Since it's not guaranteed (per the answers below), you still might consider asking the client if *they* guarantee that the .NET framework is installed. If they're a .NET shop, there's a decent chance that they already require all their employees' machines to have .NET installed.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know .NET Framework 2.0 comes pre-installed on Vista and Windows 7. However, no version of the framework comes pre-installed on Windows XP. See the following:

[What version of the .NET Framework is included in what version of the OS?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Although the .NET framework is *not* guaranteed to be installed (it is an optional component), software such as Xenocode PostBuild (discontinued, but still functional for those who have copy), [Spoon](http://spoon.net), or [Mono](http://mono-project.com) (an alternative .NET framework that happens to be embeddable) can be used to run .NET applications on PCs that otherwise wouldn't be able to because the .NET framework isn't installed.

Answer (score 1):

No it won't be guaranteed to run. .NET can be removed on XP

Answer (score 0):

Yes. .NET framework is optional for Windows XP. Windows 7 has .NET framework version 3.5 as default.